# Show subcategory instead of parent category

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am using the code below for displaying the WordPress post category but it outputs the parent category, not the subcategory. Can this be modified to show the subcategory instead?

```
<div class="category">' . get_category(get_query_var('cat'))->name . '</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to get sub-categories by ID

```
    <?php $cats = get_the_category($post->ID);
$sep = '';
foreach( $cats as $cat ) {
  $subcats = get_categories('child_of='.$cat->term_id);
  if($subcats) {
    foreach( $subcats as $subcat )
      {   echo $sep . $subcat->name; $sep = ', '; }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. That works great to get a list of the sub categories, but I want the specific subcategory of the post to show up over the image, like the date does. Here is my full code:

`if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) )
{
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '"><div class="thumb" style="background: url(' . $image[0] . ') center no-repeat;"><div class="date">' . get_the_date('M d, y') . '</div></div></a>'; }`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show list of WordPress category then use this code

```
 <div class="category"> <?php _e('Categories:'); ?> <?php wp_list_cats(); ?></div>
```

OR you want to call woocomerce category then call use this code

```
 <div class="category">
        <?php

          $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
          $orderby      = 'name';  
          $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
          $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
          $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
          $title        = '';  
          $empty        = 0;

          $args = array(
                 'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                 'orderby'      => $orderby,
                 'show_count'   => $show_count,
                 'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                 'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                 'title_li'     => $title,
                 'hide_empty'   => $empty
          );
         $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
         foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
            if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
                $category_id = $cat->term_id;       
                echo '<br /><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>';

                $args2 = array(
                        'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                        'child_of'     => 0,
                        'parent'       => $category_id,
                        'orderby'      => $orderby,
                        'show_count'   => $show_count,
                        'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                        'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                        'title_li'     => $title,
                        'hide_empty'   => $empty
                );
                $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
                if($sub_cats) {
                    foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                        echo  $sub_category->name ;
                    }   
                }
            }       
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```